# placeHolder id not displaying using style.display

Tags: javascript, css

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with my code

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p id='placeHolder' style='display: none;'>Empty NOW!</p>
    <ul class='list'>
       <li>Item One<a href='#' class='clear'>Remove</a></li>
       <li>Item Two<a href='#' class='clear'>Remove</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

$('a.clear').click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().remove();

    if($('.list li').length == 0) { 
      document.getElementById('placeHolder').style.display='block';
      console.log('its empty now');
    }

    return false;
});
```

Let's say you removed the items from the list and li is now ZERO, I'm not sure why placeHolder doesn't actually display the placeHolder?

I used console.log to make sure the length actually checked and it is a valid statement. Any suggestion on why getElementById not firing?

Comment: To start, you can replace this: `document.getElementById('placeHolder')` by this : `$('#placeHolder')` because you are using JQuery.

Comment: Item Two won't remove itself, right? It's a .remove not a .clear - so your `if` will never be true

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in the original post. I editted it.

Comment: Actually I wasn't even sure what was wrong with my code.. working now.. Gonna be scratching my head over this one

Answer (score 1):

In order to validate your condition `$('.list li').length == 0`, you have to remove the two list items, either by finding a common selector :

```
$('li a').click(function() { // the choice of the selector is of course up to you :)
    $(this).parent().remove();
    if($('.list li').length == 0) { 
      document.getElementById('placeHolder').style.display='block';
      console.log('its empty now');
    }
    return false;
});
```

or by removing the parent of the parent :       `$(this).parent().parent().remove();`

Comment: When I attempted to use style.display ='block'; it somehow gave me an error... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined